# Count number of times certain characters appears in list

Tags: python

If I have a list, `["abc123", "abc456", "abc789"]`

How do I count how many times "abc" appears?

I have already tried using .count and .find but they didn't work the way I did them

Comment: Show the way you tried to use them, and someone can probably tell you what you were doing wrong.

Comment: What was the way you did them, and what do you mean *"didn't work"*? Provide a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and useful problem statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can transform to full string and count :

```
In [1]: " ".join(["abc123", "abc456", "abc789","123abc12abc"]).count("abc")
Out[1]: 5
```

Comment: @StevenRumbalski why not ?

Answer (score 2):

```
strlist = ["abc123", "abc456", "abc789"]
sum('abc' in a for a in strlist)
```

Counts how many matches you have.

Comment: This answer will only count the first match in each string.

Comment: `sum(s.count('abc') for s in strlist)`

Comment: AJ: I thought that was what was requested.

Answer (score 1):

Get a list of the counts:

```
In [1]: counts = [s.count('abc') for s in ["abc123", "abc456", "abc789"]]
In [2]: counts
Out[2]: [1, 1, 1]
```

Sum the list of counts for total occurrences:

```
In [3]: sum(counts)
Out[3]: 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Some pseudocode to get you started as I get the feeling this could be homework/study question:

```
def count_strings(a_string, sub_string):
    the_total = 0
    for each_string in a_list:
        count sub_string in each_string
    return the_total
```